# Write a Program Detab That Replaces Tabs in the Input with the Proper Number of Blanks to Space to the Next Tab Stop

Tags: beginner, c

Continuing my K&R journey!

Please see below for my solution to:

> Exercise 1-20: Write a program detab that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number of blanks to space to the next tab stop. Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every *n* columns.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAB         '\t'        //  character to look for
#define SPACE       '-'         //  tab replacement char
#define TABSIZE     8           //  fixed set of tab stops
#define MAXLINE     8000        //  maximum number of chars in a line

static int getLine(char line[]);

static void processLine(char line[], int lineCharCount);


int main() {
    int len;                //length of line
    char line[BUFSIZ];      //string constant array for appending ch

    while ((len = getLine(line)) > 0) {
        processLine(line, len);
    }
    return 0;
}

static int getLine(char line[]) {
    int c;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        line[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

static void processLine(char line[], int lineCharCount) {
    int nonTabCount;            // running count of characters up until \t is encountered
    int i;                      // for loop
    nonTabCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lineCharCount; i++) {
        if (line[i] == TAB) {
            nonTabCount++;
            line[i] = SPACE;
            putchar(line[i]);
            while (TABSIZE - nonTabCount > 0) {
                putchar(SPACE);
                nonTabCount++;
            }
            nonTabCount = 0;
        } else {
            putchar(line[i]);
            nonTabCount++;
            if (nonTabCount >= TABSIZE) {
                nonTabCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is a hyphen the same as a space?

Comment: Oh dear, I forgot to change back to space..... having hyphens was helpful while building the program. Gosh darnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall: Aside from bug, a very good post.

---

**Nice layout & formatting**

**Good object names**

**Bug: Inconsistent size**

With `char line[BUFSIZ];` and C definition of "The value of the macro `BUFSIZ` shall be at least 256.", calling `getLine(line)` is a problem. `getLine()` assumes the buffer is `MAXLINE` or 8000.

Better to use the same.  Even better, pass the size into `getLine()`.

```
// static int getLine(char line[]) {
static size_t getLine(char line[], size_t size) {
```

I like `size` first to allow static code analysis with:

```
static size_t getLine(size_t size, char line[size]) {
```

In this case, best to initialize to handle tiny sizes.

```
// int c;
int c = 0;
```

**Pedantic: string size**

String size can exceed `INT_MAX`.  Better to use `size_t` to express `lineCharCount` to handle all strings.

```
// processLine(char line[], int lineCharCount)
processLine(char line[], size_t lineCharCount)
```

Then use `size_t i;` in the function.

**Simplify**

Simpler and handles unsigned math well - no overflow.

```
// while (TABSIZE - nonTabCount > 0) {
while (TABSIZE > nonTabCount) {
```

**Printing**

I'd print the processed line afterwards and avoid printing in `processLine()`.  Of course that is tricky as the line grows.

**Why change `line[]`?**

`processLine()` has `line[i] = SPACE;`, but why change only 1 space?  If anything the de-tabify process might add multiple spaces and that complicates things.  Code instead could  `putchar(SPACE);` and leave `line[]` unchanged.

If `processLine()` changed to leave `char line[]` unchanged, consider making that paramter `const char line[]`.

**String?**

With `processLine(char line[], int lineCharCount)`, I'd expect the function received a pointier to a *string*, in which case, the `lineCharCount` is not needed.  Instead iterate until a *null character* is found.

Yet by passing `lineCharCount` does allow handling of a line of input with a *null character* that was read - an advance functionality.

**Fixed tab size**

"Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every *n* columns." --> that sounds like `n` should be an option at program start to de-tabify at different values.  Maybe that is for the next iteration of code.

**Documentation**

Coding goal deserves to be in the code as a comment.

**Advanced: long line**

When `getLine()` fills the buffer, yet the line is still not done, consider how one would re-work the function to convey that incomplete read to the caller and if the remainder of the line should remain unread.

**Declare and initialize in one step**

```
// int nonTabCount;
// nonTabCount = 0;

int nonTabCount = 0;
```

Comment: No review on `#define SPACE       '-'` as OP already id'ed that typo.

Comment: iamericfletcher, Post lacks tests to show that code works.  Next time, consider a test harness.

Comment: I'm confused - in `getLine` in `main()`, what would be the size I'm passing into it? Would I declare `size_t size;` and then use that like so `while ((len = getLine(size, line)) > 0)`?

Comment: Also, would I keep `char line[BUFSIZ];` the way it is in `main()`?

Comment: @iamericfletcher More like in `main()`, `char line[BUFSIZ];` ... `while ((len = getLine(sizeof line, line)) > 0)`.

Comment: Ok, but now I'm getting a message from `static size_t getLine(size_t size, char line[size])` that `Parameter 'size' always equals to 8192`. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. as `getLine()` is likely called only once as `getLine(8192, ...)`.  Either also call with other sizes or remove the `static`.